# Replace Requested URL Section

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a website that includes a language specifier in the URL (ex. http://example.org/English/rest/of/url.aspx)

Using a Regex, I can parse out the language of the URL:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath, "^~/(?<language>[^/]+)/");
```

I can then check the parsed out language and determine if the language is what I want it to be:

```
match.Groups["language"].Value
```

I'm now looking for a simpler way than brutish string manipulation to replace only that language with a new language if needed.

So the URL above would be changed to http://example.org/German/rest/of/url.aspx

My initial thought was a simple search/replace however that won't work as the page name or other URL fragments may have the language name in them. I'm only concerned with the very first fragment after the root URL.

After changing the URL I would then redirect the user and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string requestUrl = "~/English/rest/of/url.aspx";
string targetLanguage = "German";
Match match = Regex.Match(requestUrl, "^~/(?<language>[^/]+)/");
if (match.Groups["language"].Value != targetLanguage)
    Response.Redirect(Regex.Replace(requestUrl, "^~/[^/]+/", string.Format("~/{0}/", targetLanguage)));
```

Comment: Doh, right in front of my face. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Uri object then use PathAndQuery to extract the then path split '/' and replace the first instance then construct your uri again